# Missing "Edit Configuration" Button on hybris backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

On Hybris 2005 Doc, it says I should see a button to edit synchronization attributes configuration on backoffice, but I can't see it there after the upgrade, and I am having a hard time to find an option to enable it. Can someone point me to to correct direction here?

[image]

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/e1d742dac110467c81ce6d6b139879e8.html

Comment: could you please share the screenshot of the problem and give it a try just press F4 and do reset everything. The above one is the expected one.

Comment: also, you can update the configuration using this Impex.
UPDATE SyncAttributeDescriptorConfig[batchmode=true];includedInSync;attributeDescriptor(qualifier, enclosingType(code))[unique=true]